# How to create multiple post request with AFHTTPRequestOperation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am new developer in IOS application.

Today, i am creating application with multiple 'post request' and i am using AFNetworking to create 'post request' in my application.

My problem in my application when i want to use NSOperationQueue for multiple 'post request'. In Readme of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) i get good code

```
NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSURL *fileURL in filesToUpload) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://localhost/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL name:@"images[]" error:nil];
    }];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[mutableOperations addObject:operation];
}

NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:@[...] progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");
}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

However, this code is not supporting my flow 'post request'.

This is my flow 'post request' in my application. I have 2 entity, User and Image. User has many Image. Before i send 'post request' for User Entity, i want to upload image belongs to user and all of 'post request' will be canceled when one of images fail to upload.
This is my code for multiple 'post request' using NSOperationQueue.

This is my code for running my flow post request :

```
- (void)postModel{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest    = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity     = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error                  = nil;
    self.Users                    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to execute fetch request.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);

    } else {
        self.uploadQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];//[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (Users *user in self.users) {
            if (user.images) {
                for (Images *image in user.images) {
                    [mutableOperations addObject:[self postImage:image]];
                }
            }
            [mutableOperations addObject:[self postUser:user]];
            for( int index = 0; index < [mutableOperations count]; index = index + 1 )
            {
                AFHTTPRequestOperation *secondOperation    = mutableOperations[index];
                if (index != 0) {
                    AFHTTPRequestOperation *firstOperation     = mutableOperations[index - 1];
                    [secondOperation addDependency:firstOperation];
                }
            }
            NSArray *operations = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableOperations];
            [self.uploadQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
        }
    }
}

-(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)postImage:(Images *)image{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context     = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSString *urlString                 = @"http://localhost/image/upload";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            if ([imageType isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [imageType isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:image.picture name:@"image_user" fileName:image.name mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            }else{
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:image.picture name:@"image_user" fileName:image.name mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }error:nil];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:600];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Image ID : %@", responseObject[@"id"]);
        NSError *error = nil;
        image.image_id = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: [responseObject[@"id"] integerValue]];
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    return operation;
}

-(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)postUser:(Users *)user{
    NSString *urlString             = @"http://localhost/user/upload";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request    = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[user.name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    name:@"name"];
        if (user.images) {
            for (Images *image in user.images) {
                [formData appendPartWithFormData:[[image.image_id stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                            name:@"images_id[]"];
            }
        }
    }error:nil];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:600];
    operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"USER ID : %@", responseObject[@"user_id"]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    return operation;
}
```

The problem with my code, i always got error code from my log of XCODE and make my application crash

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSInlineData
>   objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7ff06e1e49b0'

I got this error when my first post request is successful. However, the other post request is not sent to my local server. 
Could anyone here help me to fix my problem ?

Thanks